# allow admins to read users mails using GSuite app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

right now i'm trying to build an app for G Suit marketplace which allow the admins to read users emails using Gmail APIs. I found that we can do that by using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) but i only can access the users emails in my domain. right now i don't know how i can make admins from outside my organization use my app to read users emails

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service_file2.json'
emails=['user2@example.com','user1@example.com']


for email in emails:
    # The user we want to "impersonate"
    USER_EMAIL = email
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.\
        from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL)
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
    email_list = service.users().messages().list(userId=USER_EMAIL).execute()
    b = 3
    for m in email_list['messages']:
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=USER_EMAIL, id=m['id'], format='metadata').execute()
        print(message['payload']['headers'][1]['value'])
```